# How fix article with css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to create this mini website I am trying but I have some problems.

1- I want to color the `ul` list but only 2 of them work.

2- there is white space in the width I am trying to minimize the width of  but didn't work ,

I copied the code on `codepen` and this is a picture of what I want. Please help me . thank you.

[image]

This is how the program looks like:

[image]

This is my code: https://codepen.io/aminanba/pen/VwpOZRB

```
    article{
    width: 80%;
}


.item1 {
    grid-area:item1;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .item2 {
    grid-area: item2;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-area: item3;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  .item4 {
    grid-area: item4;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-area: item5;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    
  }

  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25% 25% 75%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "item1 item2 item2 item3"
      "item4 item5 item5 item5"
      ;
  }

h3{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

p{
    margin: 10px;
}

img{
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproduciable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including your HTML

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first one you need to close your a tags, like this;

```
<ul class="grid-item item5">
    <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Local</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Opinion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
</ul>
```

For the second one you need to make sure you do not have and margin or padding in your ul / li elements. By default the browser adds some padding to the elements. To fix this just set it to 0 for every element at the start of your stylesheet and then add margin/padding accordingly. So in your css just add at the very top the following;

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fix this with css grid but in the second section i used flexbox it is usefull

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

header{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

article{
    width: 80%;
}


.item1 {
    grid-area:item1;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .item2 {
    grid-area: item2;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-area: item3;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
  }

  .item4 {
    grid-area: item4;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-area: item5;
    
    border: 2px solid black;
    
  }

  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 50% 25% 25% 75%;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "item1 item2 item2 item3"
      "item4 item5 item5 item5"
      ;
  }

h3{
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

p{
    margin: 10px;
}

img{
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

.other-sections {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

  }
  
  .site-section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  .section-link {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Futura";
    color: #666;
  }
  
  .section-link:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
  .site-section-local {
    background-color: #55efc4;
  }
  
  .site-section-tech {
    background-color: #81ecec;
  }
  
  .site-section-opinion {
    background-color: #74b9ff;
  }
  
  .site-section-sports {
    background-color: #a29bfe;
  }
  
  .site-section-politics {
    background-color: #ffeaa7;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>News Papers</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merienda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>The News Times</h1>
    </header>
    
    <article class="grid-container">
    <section class="item1">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h3>Student Learns HTML</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ad in quas alias non! Expedita similique et dolore illum
                doloremque vel accusantium ut eos tempora sequi, doloribus vitae mollitia praesentium ex ullam? Dolorem labore fugiat
                neque nostrum porro vero fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquam corrupti, eius odio
                neque incidunt esse fuga veritatis ipsum, eligendi mollitia, porro quasi provident nisi sit! Doloribus, eligendi nemo,
                ad laudantium cupiditate aspernatur eveniet asperiores modi praesentium voluptas eos sunt odio.</p>
        </div>
    </section >
    <section class="item2">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h3>BREAKING: Puppies Are Adorable</h3>
            <img src="http://placecorgi.com/300/150" style="width:100%;" />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, dolores? Illo dolores, rerum iste aut porro doloribus fugit itaque voluptas</p>.

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium incidunt ullam ea magni ipsam perferendis ratione pariatur enim repellendus quia?</p>
        </div>
    </section >
    <section class="item3">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h3>CSS Is Apparently a Thing</h3>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic ad in quas alias non! Expedita similique et dolore illum
                doloremque vel accusantium ut eos tempora sequi, doloribus vitae mollitia praesentium ex ullam? Dolorem labore fugiat
                neque nostrum porro vero fugit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquam corrupti, eius odio
                neque incidunt esse fuga veritatis ipsum, eligendi mollitia, porro quasi provident nisi sit! Doloribus, eligendi nemo,
                ad laudantium cupiditate aspernatur eveniet asperiores modi praesentium voluptas eos sunt odio.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="item4">
        <div class="grid-item">
            <h3>Boy Likes Turtles</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, perferendis! Accusamus asperiores quod vitae architecto natus alias fugiat aliquam unde sint expedita repellat rerum, obcaecati hic placeat recusandae quaerat. Dolores excepturi earum minus magni! Animi aperiam eligendi molestias necessitatibus ducimus.

            Voluptate, ut, cupiditate ducimus vitae blanditiis ex impedit debitis est tempora dolores nam sed. Esse nobis ea inventore qui enim quia beatae ab commodi laboriosam quam aliquam aut perspiciatis fuga nam rerum temporibus voluptatum explicabo voluptate, pariatur ullam laudantium eligendi.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
   <section class="item5">
    <ul class="story three-quarter other-sections">
        <li class="site-section site-section-politics">
          <a href="#" class="section-link">
            Politics
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-section site-section-tech">
          <a href="#" class="section-link">
            Technology
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-section site-section-local">
          <a href="#" class="section-link">
            Local
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-section site-section-opinion">
          <a href="#" class="section-link">
            Opinion
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="site-section site-section-sports">
          <a href="#" class="section-link">
            Sports
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section> 
    </article>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```